# Sort list by suffix

Tags: string, sorting, suffix

I'd like to learn how to sort my plaintext file by a specific string ending, in this case the suffix '**ly**':

```
aback
abaft
abandonedly
abashedly
abeam
abed
abhorrently
...
```

With all words ending in '**ly**' extracted and or split from this list, it should resemble the following:

```
aback
abaft
abeam
abed
...
abandonedly
abashedly
abhorrently
```

Note:

- It does not matter if the new list is appended to the old list or not.
- I would prefer for my list to remain sorted alphabetically if
  possible.

I am open to using a programming language, the command line or a service. The fact is, with my previous researches online I haven't been able to determine which method is most efficient or simplest for accomplishing this sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in Python:

```py
with open("input.txt", "r") as f_in:
    lines = sorted(map(str.strip, f_in), key=lambda k: (k.endswith("ly"), k))

with open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
    print("\n".join(lines), file=f_out)
```

From `input.txt`:

```
aback
abaft
abandonedly
abashedly
abeam
abed
abhorrently
```

Creates `output.txt`:

```
aback
abaft
abeam
abed
abandonedly
abashedly
abhorrently
```